# Community Salesforce Tab+ Visualforce

Tags: community, html, custom-link

We are building a Community (SalesforceTab + Visualforce) using whitelabels. In one of those whitlelabels we have several links to an external site (code below):

```
<ul>
 <li class="footer">
    <a href="https://www.octotelematics.com/about">About us</a>
 </li>
 <li class="footer">
    <a href="https://www.octotelematics.com/contact-us">Contact us</a>
 </li>
 <li class="footer">
    <a href="#3">Terms of use</a>
 </li>
 <li class="footer">
    <a href="https://www.octotelematics.com/privacy">Privacy</a>
 </li>
 <li class="footer">
    <a href="/customer/s/whitelabel/page/faq.html">Documents &amp; FAQ</a>
 </li>
</ul>
```

When the users click on one of the link, the community throws the error that I can see in the browser console :
*XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://www.octotelematics.com/about?_=1494492063806. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'https://uat-uat-octoforce.cs87.force.com' is therefore not allowed access.*

I just tried to put *https://www.octotelematics.com/* inside the remote site settings but it didn't solve the problem.

How can I solve it?

Comment: Hi @L.benedettini,

How to reproduce this issue, can you provide steps?

Comment: Add the code provided to an html page and save it in a Site.com whitelabel. Log in the Community as the administrator and click on one of the link that you find. After that you may see the error